# Many different Invoking methods?

Tags: c#

I don´t really understand the Invoking. I get that what it´s doing is that it tells that current action to be run on the thread it needs to be ran on (UI Thread). But what i don´t get is why you can do so many different versions. for example:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { currping.Text = Status; }));

this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {  currping.Text = Status; }));
```

I don´t understand if there is a difference. They will both do the same thing from what i can grasp.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: No difference. It's just that the language is evolving to make things easier to code.

Comment: Ah well that´s good to know, MethodInvoker is not to be used than just for the safety of it. But is Action the "latest and greatest", or is there any newer versions of invoking?

Comment: Add: You could even remove the _new Action()_ from the second type: _this.BeginInvoke(() => {  currping.Text = Status; });_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen No, you can't. `BeginInvoke()` takes a `Delegate`. See my answer for why you need `new Action` or a cast to `Action`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Action` was added in the .NET 3.5 framework as a general delegate that takes no arguments and returns nothing, while `MethodInvoker` has existed since 1.1, so you'll typically only see older code using `MethodInvoker`.  The two delegate types have the same signature.

`BeginInvoke()` actually takes a `Delegate` object, so any delegate that takes no arguments can be used with that overload.  (There is a `(Delegate, object[])` overload for delegates that need arguments, though I'd be inclined to use a no-argument closure instead.)

Because `Delegate` is a general type, you must specify in some way what type of delegate you are providing because the compiler cannot otherwise infer it (see below).  This is shorter than the `new Action` alternative, but only by a few characters and it isn't really any more or less clear:

```
this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { ... }));
```

You have to specify a delegate type here because the compiler doesn't know which delegate type you want.  For example:

```
Action foo = () => { };
```

This works because the compiler can infer based on the type of `foo` that the delegate type should be `Action`.

```
// All of these examples cause CS1660.
Delegate foo1 = () => { };
object foo2 = () => { };
var foo3 = () => { };
```

These are compile-time errors because there are many delegate types that match the signature "takes no arguments and returns `void`" and the compiler doesn't pretend to know which you wanted.  (And in the `object` and `var` cases, you may also have meant an `Expression<>` object, which isn't a delegate at all.  Nevertheless, you'd get the same error if you used `delegate () {}` instead of a lambda expression.)

Comment: Well, that explains it, as well as the comment in my question. Good that it isn´t something i missed then. But well, what do people use, did Net Framework 4/4.5 introduce anything? (Would like to use the shortest one, as it´s pretty frustrating code to write so much, to do one thing).

Comment: Also, is there any difference between. this.BeginInvoke, and label.BeginInvoke (as both are on the same thread)?

Comment: @user2587718 Updated my answer a bit, as I did some research and found my answer partially incorrect.  No, there should be no difference between `BeginInvoke()` on any particular control if they are all on the same thread, but as a best practice I try to invoke on the control I am mutating in case its owning thread changes in the future.

Comment: What do you mean, No argument closure? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Great, well indeed, also makes it more clear to What object you are actually using it on.

Comment: @user2587718 I mean that I would prefer `x.BeginInvoke((Action)() => { x.Text = y; })` over `x.BeginInvoke((Action<string>)(z => x.Text = z), y)`. The former will be faster and is also considerably more readable, though it also has some confusing caveats if you're not familiar with the concept of closure and upvalues.

Comment: Ah, well that´s what i am using, didn´t even know you could put an argument, makes it more confusing, but good that it doesn´t really matter for this.

Comment: Okay this just made it alot harder to understand. But even if the compiler doesn´t know or care what i wanted, as long as i just specify X.BeginInvoke... i should be fine, right? As it got the Label, for example, and know it needs to run on the UI Thread. . Btw, this doesn´t work for me: this.BeginInvoke((Action)() => { ... }); you sure it´s correct?

Comment: @user2587718 I updated my sample. In that case the syntax is a bit wonky and you need an extra set of parens: `(Action)(() => {})`.  *"But even if the compiler doesn't know or care what i wanted, as long as i just specify"* <-- I don't know what you mean by this.

Comment: nice, yeah noticed that when i played around.  What i meant with that was,i don´t tell the Action anything, what it is, or any argument, so from what i understand, the compiler will just guess. But is it something i have to care about? cause i get confused when i look at your "foo" examples.

Comment: The compiler will infer the type from the context.  If it cannot infer a concrete delegate type then you have to explicitly specify one.

Answer (score 1):

There are two pieces to this the `new Something(` part and the part inside the inner most parenthesis.

Both `MethodInvoker` and `Action` are [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you need to think of them like "Function pattern" definitions. What both of those two "patterns" represent is "a function that accepts no arguments and returns void"

```
namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    public delegate void MethodInvoker();
}

namespace System
{
    public delegate void Action()
}
```

So they both represent the exact same "pattern" it is just defined in two places for coding convenience. For example it is more obvious that you are planning on using the delegate to invoke a method for a Winforms Form using `MethodInvoker` than using `Action`.

the 2nd part is the stuff inside the parenthesis. Both of those two definitions mean the same thing, however the pattern `() => { ... }` is a [Lambada Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and was not added till visual studio 2008 or newer. They both mean is just "I am defining a function here inline", this creates what is called an [Anonymous Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx) because it is a function with no name. You also could pass a function name in instead

```
public void Foo()
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(Bar)); //BeginInvoke will call the function Bar()
}

private void Bar()
{
}
```